# In Vim, is there a way to paste text in the search line?

Tags: vim

I want to search for `$maximumTotalAllowedAfterFinish` and replace it with `$minimumTotalAllowedAfterFinish`. Instead of typing the long text:

```
:%s/$maximumTotalAllowedAfterFinish/$minimumTotalAllowedAfterFinish/g
```

Is there a way to COPY these long variable names down into the search line, since, on the command line I can't type "`p`" to paste?

Comment: I guess that tou also need to escape the first `$` because this caracter means the end of line.

Comment: @LucM The OP could also use `\V` anywhere in the search pattern to disable "magic" characters.

Answer (score 171, accepted):

You can insert the contents of a numbered or named register by typing <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> <kbd>`{0-9a-z"%#:-=.}`</kbd>. By typing <kbd>CTRL-R</kbd> <kbd>CTRL-W</kbd> you can paste the current word under the cursor. See:

```
:he cmdline-editing
```

for more information.

Comment: thanks for answer, the most common one for me is: `CTRL` + `R` `+` (as it goes for the the clipboard contents)

Comment: The `0` register contains the last-yanked string.

Answer (score 69):

Copy it as normal, then do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd><kbd>"</kbd> to paste. There are lots of other <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> shortcuts (e.g, a calculator, current filename, clipboard contents). Type `:help c_<C-R>` to see the full list.

Answer (score 36):

Copy:
1) `v` (or highlight with mouse, in visual mode) 
2) `y` (yank)

Paste:
1) `/` (search mode)
2) `Ctrl + R + 0` (paste from yanked register)

Comment: I was looking for this answer when I searched for this question in google, I wonder why this has negative votes.

Answer (score 17):

Type `q:` to get into history editing mode in a new buffer. Then edit the last line of the buffer and press `Enter` to execute it.

Comment: So that's what that buffer was for! Thanks (I always just happened to stumble on it when typing :q and get confused)

Comment: `q/` is also useful to access the search history and paste new searches.

Answer (score 3):

Or create the command in a vim buffer , e.g. type it in the buffer:

```
s/foo/bar/gci
```

And copy it to a named register, with `"ayy` (if the cursor is on that line!).

Now you can execute the contents of the "`a`" register from Vim's Ex command line with:

```
:[OPTIONAL_RANGE]@a
```

I use it all the time.

Comment: your "ayy" either is quoted (and therefore incorrect) or it's not (and therefore there's an erroneous " at the end)

Answer (score 3):

You can place the cursor on the word that you want to add to your pattern and then press <kbd>/</kbd> or <kbd>:</kbd> to enter either the search or the command mode, and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> to copy the word. [Source](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/1870/bring-the-word-under-the-cursor-on-the-ex-line-in-vim)

Answer (score 2):

Typically, you would do that with mouse selecting (perhaps <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Ins</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> after selecting) and then, when in the command/search line, middle-clicking (or <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ins</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>).

Another way, is to write your command/search line in the text buffer with all the editing available in text buffers, starting with `:` and all, then, on the line, do:

```
"add@a
```

which will store the whole command line in buffer `a`, and then execute it. It won't be stored in the command history, though.

Try creating the following line in the text buffer as an example for the key presses above:

```
:%s/$maximumTotalAllowedAfterFinish/$minimumTotalAllowedAfterFinish/g
```

Finally, you can enter `q:` to enter history editing in a text buffer.

Answer (score 0):

add a line: `cnoremap <c-v> <c-r>+` in your vimrc, then you can use ctrl-v to paste.